# is there a documented list of objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item s somewhere

Tags: vba, smtp, smtp-auth

I believe that we need to move to Oauth2 for sending emails from vba via smtp

I have found a reasonable sample code written in vb but not in vba

Here are some sample configuration fields that I am using at the moment but I will need to know the configurations for "use Oauth" and "token"

```
objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
     
objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"

objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587 
      objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxxxx"
      objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "yyyyy"
      objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
      
objSMTP.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls") = True
```

Can anyone tell me where I can find a complete list of these please

Many thanks in advance

Tony